# What is the Mockito equivalent of expect().andReturn().times()

Tags: java, junit, mockito, easymock

I've been experimenting the Mockito equivalent of the

```
EasyMock.expect(someMethod()).andReturn(someMockObject).times(n);
```

but I can't figure it out.

A little help on this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
when(myObject.someMethod()).thenReturn(someMockObject);
// run test
verify(myObject, times(n)).someMethod();
```

See the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockitoVSEasyMock) for more conversion examples.

Comment: Also note that Mockito generally discourages overdoing verify. Think about whether you really need to verify each call. (Most of the time, these are just dependencies that will blow up if they mess up anyway.)